# query list of dijit checkboxes inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to find all dijit.form.CheckBox widgets inside a DIV and enable/disable them all. I am not able to form appropriate query for it.

I tried `dojo.query("[dojoType~=dijit.form.CheckBox]")` but it gives me an empty list.

What is the appropriate query for it? Can DOJO query return a WidgetSet or does it always returns DOM ids? Is there some different way for querying dijit widgets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [dijit.findWidgets](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dijit.findWidgets):

> Search subtree under root, putting
>   found widgets in outAry. Doesn't
>   search for nested widgets (ie, widgets
>   inside other widgets)

Comment: Thanx. ``dijit.findWidgets`` works. Apart from this, to filter out the checkbox widgets, I wrote something like ``dojo.filter(widgets,function(w) {return w.declaredClass =='dijit.form.CheckBox';});``.

Comment: For dojo 1.8, dijit.findWidgets can be found at http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dijit/registry#findWidgets

Answer (score 0):

This is 1.7 > code and will search recursively for widgets instead of just direct descendents as is the case for `findWidgets`

need to require `"dojo/query"` and optionally `"dijit/registry"`

```
var checkboxes = query("input[type=checkbox]:checked", "myForm");
checkboxes.forEach((function (checkbox) {
    //dom node
    console.log(checkbox);

    //dijit
    console.log(registry.byId(checkbox.id));
}));
```

This queries checked checkboxes underneath a dom node id `myForm` and loops through the results and prints the element. Note that this only gives dom node elements in the result set so if you want to get the dijits you can use `registry.byId(...)`